# Eliminating "not in" for SQL command

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to take a sample of an Oracle table, but not include entries from another table.  I have a query that currently works, but I'm pretty sure it will blow-up when the sub-select gets more than 1000 records.

```
select user_key from users sample(5)
where active_flag = 'Y'
and user_key not in (
    select user_key from user_validation where validation_state <> 'expired'
);
```

How could this be re-written *without* the `not in`.  I thought of using `minus`, but then my sample size would keep going down as new entries were added to the user_validation table.

Comment: The 1000 limit is [on expression lists](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/expressions015.htm), i.e. a hard-coded list of comma-separated values. It does not apply to the results of a sub-select like this - it doesn't matter how many `user_key` values that excludes. Still worth looking at the alternatives though.

Comment: @AlexPoole, thanks for that insight!  If it's not going to blow-up on me when it gets big, I'm good with it.  But I learned a lot from the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `left outer join`:

```
select *
from (select u.user_key,
             count(*) over () as numrecs
      from users u left outer join
           user_validation uv
           on u.user_key = uv.user_key and
              uv.validation_state <> 'expired'
      where u.active_flag = 'Y' and uv.user_key is null
     ) t
where rownum <= numrecs * 0.05
```

You are using the sample clause.  It is not clear if you just want the non-matches in the 5% you choose or if you want 5% of the data that is non-matches.  This is the latter.

EDIT: Added example based on author's comment:

```
select user_key from (
  select u.user_key, row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) as randval
  from users u 
    left outer join user_validation uv 
    on u.user_key = uv.user_key 
    and uv.validation_state <> 'expired'
  where u.active_flag = 'Y' 
  and uv.user_key is null
) myrandomjoin where randval <=100;
```

Comment: I want a random sample, which is the reason I went with sample(5).  I don't think this gives a random sample, does it?  Left outer join might be an idea to proceed with, though.

Comment: The idea was to eliminate the non matches first, and take 5% of that.

Comment: @Dale . . . That is what this does.  If you want a random sample, you can use something like `row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) as seqnum` in the subquery, and then filter on seqnum.

Comment: If it passes muster, I've added more code to your answer based on the `order by dbms_random.value` idea.  It's no longer a percentage random selection, but a fixed value is fine (even better).

Answer (score 2):

```
select us.user_key
from users us -- sample(5)
where us.active_flag = 'Y'
and NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    from user_validation nx
    where nx.user_key = us.user_key
    AND nx.validation_state <> 'expired'
    );
```

BTW: I commented-out the sample(5) because I don't know what it means. (I strongly believe that it is not relevant, though)

Comment: the sample(5) means take a random sample of 5% of the records of the table.  But it looks like this might work for me.

Comment: Then, (as I expected) it is orthogonal to the rest of the query. Just like TOP/LIMIT, it only applies to the *outside* query.

Answer (score 1):

```
select u.user_key from users u, user_validation uv
where u.active_flag = 'Y'
and u.user_key=uv.user_key 
uv.validation_state= 'expired';
```

This was a double negation query, x not in list of non expired ids, which is equivalent to x is in the list of expired IDs, which is what I did, in addition to changing the subquery to a join.

Comment: Can you add some explanations to what you propose? What exactly have you changed and why?

Comment: By removing the double negation you changed the meaning of the query. For instance a user with  *NO corresponding record* in user_validation will be shown in the original query, but not in yours.

Comment: Please, always explicitly state your joins, don't use the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause).  Especially because I was expecting some sort of `LEFT JOIN` (like Gordon uses).

Comment: Also, the behavior of this query will be different if *more than one matching records* for users would exist in user_validation. (both `NOT IN()` and `NOT EXISTS()` ignore duplicates in the subquery)

Comment: @wildplasser is correct in saying "removing the double negation you changed the meaning of the query"; validation_state can be one of 6 or so things.